# IE Conditional comments and meta-content tags order of evaluation

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a website hosted on the local intranet, *mysite.mycompany.com*, which triggers IE to use compatibility mode (IE-7 in my case) by default.

I want [use the latest browser mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge) (hence the `meta content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"`) and handle old versions robustly (display a message for less than IE9).

My problem is that the conditional comments are evaluated prior to the meta tags, so we're still in IE-7 mode when evaluating the conditionals. For example, the following HTML using IE9 on the local intranet displays: *'Tags LT IE9'*.

What is the correct, robust way to handle this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><p>Tags LT IE9</p><![endif]-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `http-equiv` values have never been that reliable.  Instead of trying to set HTTP headers after the fact with HTML elements, just set the HTTP headers directly in either [`.htaccess`](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/master/apache/.htaccess#L91) or [`web.config`](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/master/iis/dotnet%204/webforms/web.config#L130) (depending on whether you have Apache or IIS respectively).